# I am having trouble try and catch method for NullPointerException.

Tags: java

Code:

```
package exceptiona;

import java.io.IOException

public class ExceptionTest {

@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    // call exceptionA
    try{
        throw new ExceptionA();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(};
        System.out.println ("threw Exception A")

    // call exceptionB
    try{
        throw new ExceptionB();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(};
        System.out.println ("threw Exception B")

    // throw a NullPointerException
    try{
        throw new NullPointerException
    } catch (NullPointerException){
        nu
    }
    // throw IOException
    try{
        throw new IOException();
    } catch (IOException io){
        io.printStackTrace();

    }    
}        
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: e.printStackTrace(}; it is wrong. Change to e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Catch NPE? Generally speaking, shouldn't be catching RuntimeExceptions. These exceptions most likely mean your code logic is wrong.

Comment: And anyway, this does not compile.

Comment: Please explain in the body of your post what you're actually trying to do, what you expect to happen, and what's actually happening.

Comment: r u using notepad? you can consider using eclipse or netbeans ;)

Comment: Questions end with the character `'?'`.

Answer (score 2):

You have several syntax errors:

```
// throw a NullPointerException
try{
    throw new NullPointerException();
} catch (NullPointerException npe){
    npe.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should definitely learn java syntax in order to start coding.

Refer [here for tutorials to get started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

in the second catch, you have a syntax error:

change

```
e.printStackTrace(};
```

to

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: The same error can be found in the first catch, neither of the first two catch blocks has a closing brace, and in the NPE catch block, `nu` isn't a valid statement.

Comment: yeah lots of issue in that code.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should avoid catching NullPointerException as they are runtime and show a wrong code logic.

What you should do is make sure you don't give null arguments to methods that should not be null.

Comment: Judging by the fact that the entire program is throwing and catching exceptions, it seems more like an exercise in learning about try, catch, and throw. The fact that OP is catching an NPE isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ExceptionTest {

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // call exceptionA
        try {
            throw new ExceptionA();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("threw Exception A");

            // call exceptionB
            try {
                throw new ExceptionB();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("threw Exception B");

                // throw a NullPointerException
                try {
                    throw new NullPointerException();
                } catch (NullPointerException nu) {

                }
                // throw IOException
                try {
                    throw new IOException();
                } catch (IOException io) {
                    io.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is slightly off use this one:

```
try{
    throw new ExceptionA();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println ("threw Exception A");
}
// call exceptionB
try{
    throw new ExceptionB();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println ("threw Exception B");
}
```

After this you use a word called: "nu"?

```
try{
    throw new NullPointerException(); //missing ();
} catch (NullPointerException np){
    //nu ?
    System.out.println("threw NullPointerException");
}
```